# PHP Spreadsheet date validation

Tags: php, excel, validation, spreadsheet

So Im wondering how could I create a validation for date while generating excel?
I read on [data validation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#setting-data-validation-on-a-cell) also some articles only suggest `setFormatCode` which is not I guess validating the,

the [data validation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#setting-data-validation-on-a-cell) which has a whole number example works,

Then upon reading on [API](https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/classes/PhpOffice-PhpSpreadsheet-Cell-DataValidation.html) there is a `DATE_TYPE` which is I tried to use but still not generating a date type validation upon creating excel

```php
$validation=$sheet->getCell('A3')->getDataValidation();
$validation->setType( \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataValidation::TYPE_DATE );
$validation->setErrorStyle( \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataValidation::STYLE_STOP );
$validation->setAllowBlank(true);
$validation->setOperator('isValidDate');
$validation->setErrorTitle('Oops!');
$validation->setError('Invalid date.');
```

My question is, does spreadsheet support date validation? and if not why is there a date type and not having a valid date operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it does support date validation but, its not that kind of effective, when viewed by Google Sheets or Microsoft Excel it gets override, then the date format will be converted in to text and the validation will not work any longer.